# Git SHA-1 hash building: commit vs. tag?

Tags: git, git-commit, sha1, sha, git-tag

I've successfully been able to figure out how to piece together a Git `commit` hash from the data.

I can construct an algorithm that makes a Call to SHA-1 using each "piece" of information (tree, author, committer, etc)
and surprisingly enough, my hash matches up with the git hash the commit gets. Based on my experimentation, there is some strangeness with newlines but the format for how these should be handled is something like:

```
tree ***\n
parent ***\n
author *** *** ***\n
commiter *** *** ***\n
gpgsig ***\n
\n***\n
```

Where `***` represents the actual normal *input*.

---

Now I am trying to do the same for **annotated tags**, but struggling to get the same SHA-1 output that git gives.

Some obvious differences stand out:

- the message now comes *before* the PGP sig
- the PGP sig is not prefixed with "gpgsig "

No matter how many combinations of weird newlines I try, I *cannot* get my algorithm to correctly build a SHA-1 hash based on this output.

The most *logical* format for how I see this is:

```
object ***\n
type ***\n
tag ***\n
tagger *** *** ***\n
\n***\n
***\n
```

Questions:

- Is there anything else that's different about annotated tag generation? Is my format assumptions wrong?
- Is the output of `git cat-file` equivalent to how I should be piecing this together? I am assuming so because the commit worked that way, but would be nice to confirm.
- Git is open-source, right? Does anyone have a link for how they build the SHA-1 hash? Would be awesome to do this in a way that isn't guess and check.

Thanks in advance for the help, really struggling with this!

ANSWER: there is a space in gpgsig ONLY on commits

Comment: Check that you generate the exact same content : `git cat-file -p mytag > expected` vs `run my script > got`

Comment: It seems that the content matches, although admittedly sometimes it is hard to tell even with that (e.g. is the newline at the *start* of the message or at the end of the tagger). Is `git cat-file -p <hash>` 100% accurate to what was input to SHA-1?

Comment: you can confirm that in the terminal : `(printf "tag %d\0" $(git cat-file -p mytag | wc -c); git cat-file -p mytag) | sha1sum`

Comment: "It seems that the content matches" : have you used `diff got expected` or `got == expected` in your code to check for an exact, byte for byte comparison ? do also check that the way you generate the complete tag content (`encode("tag ", data.length, 0x0, data)`) produces the expected output (compare it to the `(printf "tag ...)` output above)

Comment: also : what's the scripting language you use ? what OS and terminal are you running on ?

Comment: Thanks, terminal seems to work, so I just need to make the algorithm in Typescript/Javascript properly. I expect it's some newline occurrences that are throwing me off. Would my tag *format* posted in question be correct, or is there some mistake with the newlines?

Comment: it looks correct. Inspect the bytes in the output of `git cat-file`, or of the "shell" version : `<command> | hexdump` or `<command> | hd`.

Comment: ANSWER: For some reason, I swear to god, on commits there is a space AFTER the newlines in the gpgsig. On tags there are not...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `git cat-file -p <object>` outputs the exact content of the object stored in git (`\n` and `\r\n` and all included).

Here is one way to generate the complete object's content (including the leading `tag <lenght>\0`) from the terminal :

```
printf "tag %d\0" $(git cat-file -p mytag | wc -c); git cat-file -p mytag

# to check if it has the correct hash:
(print "tag ...) | sha1sum
```

You should compare the output of this command with the content generated by your code :

```
encode("tag ", data.length, "\0", data)
```

for example :

```
(printf "tag ...) > expected.txt
node myscript.js  > got.txt

diff expected.txt got.txt || echo "** content is different"
```

---

I was asking about your OS and terminal because, on Windows, some tools or libraries may insert `\r\n` insert of `\n` when you ask for a newline, and Powershell is known to meddle with your output without you knowing -- the parameters to set to just have UTF-8 as output are tricky to set right, and until a few versions ago it would always "helpfully" insert a BOM at the beginning of your output.

This wouldn't apply to strings manipulated within your program, but this may be leading you to think that your code produce weird things when it is actually the shell.

Answer (score 1):

First: yes, Git is open-source; see [the public mirror here](https://github.com/git/git) for instance.

The hash of an annotated tag is that of the tag's data *including the signature:*

```
$ git rev-parse v2.35.0
38fc0d036c2e0267736249eae49fb9df786fe87b
$ git cat-file -p v2.35.0
object 89bece5c8c96f0b962cfc89e63f82d603fd60bed
type commit
tag v2.35.0
tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1643045149 -0800

Git 2.35
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=VCUV
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
$ git cat-file -p v2.35.0 | git hash-object -t tag --stdin
38fc0d036c2e0267736249eae49fb9df786fe87b
```

Note how the produced hash matches the tag.  We can reproduce this in Python:

```py
>>> import hashlib
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("git cat-file -p v2.35.0", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> s = p.stdout.read()
>>> p.wait()
0
>>> prefix = f"tag {len(s)}\0".encode('utf8')
>>> prefix
b'tag 974\x00'
>>> h = hashlib.sha1()
>>> h.update(prefix)
>>> h.update(s)
>>> h.hexdigest()
'38fc0d036c2e0267736249eae49fb9df786fe87b'
```

which shows there's nothing special going on here.

This is the same as for commits, signed or otherwise.  The raw data is the raw data; it gets prefixed with the object type (one of "blob", "commit", "tag", or "tree"), an ASCII space, the decimalized length of the object also in ASCII, and a NUL byte.  We then compute a SHA1 (or, with the new SHA-256 mode, a SHA256) hash of those bytes and that's the Git-level object hash ID.

Note that the signature *in* the tag or *in* the commit is a GPG or ssh or whatever digital signature of *some of the data*, not all of it: we can't sign our own signature until we have the signature, so there's a chicken-and-egg issue here.  So we sign the commit or tag minus the signature itself, then encode the signature bytes, then compute the hash of the whole thing.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your help. Turns out on commits there is a space AFTER the newlines in the gpgsig. On tags there are not.

Comment: Yes: notice how in the commit, the *entire* GPG signature is indented. This makes sure it is all part of a commit "header", as the first *completely blank line* separates the header (which Git does not print, but rather parses and interprets) from the subject-and-body (which `git log` prints). To avoid complications, Git simply inserts a blank after newlines here. To verify the signature, read out the commit, strip those blanks and the signature, and re-sign and compare signatures.

Comment: (Git now comes with some signature verifier programs so that you don't have to know how to do this yourself.)

Comment: Thanks @torek, do you happen to know if there are any Javascript versions of this kind of signature verification or Git helpers to avoid this?

Comment: I know of none, which does not mean they don't exist: I avoid Javascript assiduously.